# How to send params to partial views (and how to read them)

Tags: parameters, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-5

new at web hope I get this right:

part of my form appears  in two pages - one with all fields blocked, and the second is all fields are available to fill in (BTW - I need to bind the mutual model between the view and its partial view)

I think like back end dev, and decided to have partial view and call it in two places with param (AreFieldsBlocked..). I understand the communication between view and parrtial view is within ViewBag? not so strongly typed..

What would be the best way to divide that so the code will be maintainable and readable?

Answer (score 0):

Use of Child Actions will be appropriate in your situation

Comment: This is an accurate but fairly weak answer. Admittedly, the OP gave a fairly weak scenario, but code examples of call and action method would improve the answer significantly.